# Использование спецификатора auto в цикле for each

Tags: c++-cli

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой в **MS VS 2015** и может предоставить ссылку на соответствующий раздел документации на сайте Microsoft?

Следующая программа на **C++/CLI** успешно компилируется

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<String ^> ^a = { "one", "two", "three" };

    for each (auto s in a) Console::Write("{0} ", s);
    Console::WriteLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание на использование слова `auto` в предложении с `for each`.

Однако если использовать двухмерный массив, как показано в следующей программе

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<String ^, 2> ^a =
    {
        { "one", "two" },
        { "three", "four" }
    };

    for each (auto s in a) Console::Write("{0} ", s);
    Console::WriteLine();

    return 0;
}
```

то компилятор уже не пропускает такой код и выдает сообщение об ошибке

> Ошибка    C3537   нельзя привести к типу, содержащему "auto"
>   Ошибка    C2440   static_cast: невозможно преобразовать "System::String ^"
>   в "int"

Ежели заменить слово `auto` на `String ^`, то программа будет успешно компилироваться.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<String ^, 2> ^a =
    {
        { "one", "two" },
        { "three", "four" }
    };

    for each (String ^s in a) Console::Write("{0} ", s);
    Console::WriteLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Хотелось бы посмотреть на описание данного ограничения в первоисточнике, то есть в документации на сайте Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я просмотрел раздел 16.2.1 [стандарта](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf), и ничего, отличающего случай одномерных от случая многомерных массивов, не нашёл.

В стандарте упоминается следующее раскрытие цикла:

```
for each (T d in <collection-expr>) statement
```

раскрывается в

```
<enumeration-type> e = <collection-expr>.GetEnumerator(); 
while(e.MoveNext())
{ // в стандарте эта скобка пропущена, очевидная опечатка
    T d = safe_cast<T>(e.Current); 
    statement
}
```

Видимо, для нашего случая `T == auto` и компиляция `safe_cast<T>` проваливается. Таким образом, здесь вопрос в порядке подстановки `auto` и раскрытия. И поскольку раскрытие цикла происходит чисто синтаксически (посмотрите на определение `collection pattern`!), то скорее всего, оно выполняется до семантического анализа и определения смысла `auto`.

Тем не менее, случай одномерного массива работает. Исходя из того, что эти случаи не различимы согласно стандарту, *вы наткнулись на баг*: одномерный случай, очевидно, обрабатывается специальным образом.

---

Разница между одномерным и многомерным массивами заключается ещё и в том, что первый имплементирует как `IEnumerable<String^>`, так и необобщённый `IEnumerable`, а второй — только необобщённый вариант. Но тест кастомного класса, имплементирующего лишь `IEnumerable`, проходит без ошибок.

---

P.S.: Если у вас есть возможность слезть с C++/CLI и перелезть на C#, поверьте, это стоит того.

Comment: Так как я безработный, то мне все равно, на чем сидеть.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Тем более, если уж вы берётесь за .NET, и явных требований нет, порекомендовал бы C#.

Comment: _"только необобщённый вариант"_ - ого, [действительно так](http://ideone.com/y6VrUO). А почему так сделано?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Пока не знаю, поищу, может, интернет знает.